# Using Backbone Relational, how to Store Array of Object IDs in Mongoose, Retrieve as Objects, Save Back as IDs

Tags: backbone.js, mongoose, backbone-relational

Here's my situation:

I have a Mongo Database with the following schemas:

```
var SurveySchema = new Schema({
    start_date: Date,
    end_date: Date,
    title: String,
    questions: [ObjectId] //this I want to refer to questions
});

var QuestionSchema = new Schema({
    question_text: String,
    type: String,
    ....... (Lots and lots of fields)
});
```

Full Schema file: https://github.com/nycitt/node-survey-builder-api-server/blob/master/schemas.js

Backbone models: https://github.com/nycitt/node-survey-builder/blob/master/app/js/survey-builder/models.js and collection https://github.com/nycitt/node-survey-builder/blob/master/app/js/survey-builder/collections.js

The Questions should be able to stand alone (be part of 2-3 surveys say). But a survey should refer to the question.

My ideal flow would be:

1. Backbone calls: GET /api/survey/123 and retreives the survey object where Mongoose translates the Object IDs to actual objects (does the join)
2. Backbone calls: POST /api/survey/123 posting ONLY the IDs of the questions (is there some Backbone Relational magic to do this)

Comment: Exactly a year later i'm wondering the same thing...